# How to show popover when input loses focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to show a popover when an input loses focus and keep showing it untill certain conditions are met? I've managed to do the last part, but the popover only shows when I click the input twice.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$.ajax({

        type    : "post",
        url     : "dnivalidation",
        data    : {dni : dni}
    }).success(function(){
        console.log("ID not found, you can proceed with registration");
    }).fail(function(){

        $("#per_dni").popover({
            html    : true,
            title   : 'User already exists',
            content : 'Do you want to mak an <a href=schedule.jsp>appointment</a>?'
        });

        $("#rClient").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in . . .

```
    ....

    $("#per_dni").popover({
        html    : true,
        title   : 'User already exists',
        content : 'Do you want to mak an <a href=schedule.jsp>appointment</a>?'
    });

    $("#per_dni").focusIn(function(){
        $(this).popover('show');
    });

    ....
```

And then, in some other function, call the following...

```
    $("#per_dni").popover('hide');
```

...to hide it ***/